# bash- replace empty field with . in piped statement

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm looping over a list of files, while for each file im scanning for specific things to grep out.

```
    # create .fus file
    grep DIF $file | awk '{
            if ( $7 != $13 )
                    print $4, "\t", $5, "\t", $20, "\t", $10, "\t", $11, "\t", $22, "\t", "Null";
    }' > $file_name.fus

    # create .inv_fus file
    grep DIF $file | awk '{
            if ( $7 == $13 )
                    print $4, "\t", $5, "\t", $20, "\t", $10, "\t", $11, "\t", $22, "\t", "Null";
    }' > $file_name.inv_fus

    # create .del file
    echo -e '1\t1\t1\t1' > ${file_name}.del
    echo -e '1\t1\t1\t3' >> ${file_name}.del
    grep DEL ${file} | awk '{print $4, "\t", $5, "\t", $12, "\t", "2"}' >> ${file_name}.del
```

The first awk checks if the values of column 7 and 13 are different, if they are, write to file.
The second awk checks if hte values are the same, if they are, write to file. The third creates a file with 2 lines always the same, and the rest filled in by lines containing 'DEL'.

The output files I use to generate a plot, but this fails because some fields are empty. How can I change my code (I guess the awk statement ?) so that it checks for empty fields (for columns 4, 5, 20, 10, 11 and 22) and replace empty columns with dots '.' ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by cleaning up your script. Replace the whole thing with just one simple awk command:

```
awk -v file_name="$file_name" '
BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print 1, 1, 1, 1 ORS 1, 1, 1, 3 > (file_name ".del")}
/DIF/ {print $4, $5, $20, $10, $11, $22, "Null" > (file_name "." ($7==$13?"inv_":"") "fus")}
/DEL/ {print $4, $5, $12, 2 > (file_name ".del")}
' "$file"
```

Now, update your question with sample input and expected output that captures what else you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other response has said, there's a lot of simplification that could happen here, but without knowing input or expected output its hard to comment on what changes would be beneficial.

Regardless, the question seems to boil down to replacing empty fields with dots in your output for some process down the line.  Adding a function like this to your awk scripts would seem to do the trick:

```
function clean() {
         for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { if($i==""){$i="."}; }
        }
```

For example, given this input in test.txt:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4
b1,,b3,b4
,,c3,
d1,d2,d3,
```

Running the following awk results in empty fields being periods.

```
awk -F',' 'function clean() {
           for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { if($i==""){$i="."}; }
           }
          BEGIN {OFS=","}
          {clean(); print;}' test.txt
```

Example output:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4
b1,.,b3,b4
.,.,c3,.
d1,d2,d3,.
```

Comment: My question would be - why does it matter if a field contains a "." or not? I suspect the answer will be "because I'm not specifying in my next awk (or whatever) command that the fields are tab-separated".

Comment: As I said in my first post: The output files I use to generate a plot, but this fails because some fields are empty. The plot is generated with R, which cant handle empty fields (or at leas the script cant). I'm not aiming for efficiency since the script only has to run once, I just want (hopefully in 1 elegant command) a way to both do the check ($7 == $13) and also replace empty fields with a .  I'll check if this works in a bit, thanks for both of your inputs so far